# Creating a relationship through Ajax Request in Neo4j

Tags: jquery, neo4j

I am trying to create a relationship between two nodes through ajax request. Below is my code -

```
var restServerURL = "http://localhost:7474/db/data";
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: restServerURL + "/node/1/relationships",
    dataType: "json",
    to: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function( data, xhr, textStatus ) {
         console.log("success"+data);
    },
    error: function( xhr ) {
        window.console && console.log( xhr );
        console.log("error");
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log("complete function");   
    }
});
```

Am I setting any parameter wrong? It's not creating relationship in Neo4j and going to error block. In url and to attributes 1 and 2 are the id properties of nodes.

Source Node Information for relationship -

```
<id>:584
name:trt
id:1
index:1
weight:0
x:250.48512294215675
y:138.53438454446515
px:250.79081359249457
```

Target Node Information For Relationship-

```
<id>:583
name:t
id:2
index:2
weight:0
x:335.564840711768
y:255.65841599561486
px:335.4984412139487
py:255.42282166757116
```

Please suggest the solution/rectification.

Answer (score 0):

In the object you are passing to `$.ajax()` you should remove this property/line:

```
to: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2",
```

and replace with:

```
data: {"to": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2", "type": "REL_TYPE_HERE"}
```

Also, be sure to specify the [correct authentication header](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html) if authentication is enabled for Neo4j. What is the status code of the response?

Comment: Thanks so much William for the reply. I tried the way you told and now its throwing below error -

Comment: "data is {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\r\n  \"message\" : \"Unrecognized token 'to': was expecting  [line: 1, column: 3]\",\r\n  \"exception\" : \"BadInputException\",\r\n  \"fullname\" : \"org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.BadInputException\",\r\n  \"stackTrace\" : [ \"org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.formats.JsonFormat.readMap(JsonFormat.java:94)\", \"org.neo4j.server.rest.web.RestfulGraphDatabase.createRelationship(RestfulGraphDatabase.java:570)\", \"java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\",

Comment: \"org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)\", \"org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:120)\", \"java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\" ],\r\n  \"cause\" : {\r\n    \"message\" : \"Unrecognized token 'to': was expecting  [line: 1, column: 3]\",\r\n    \"errors\" : [ {\r\n      \"message\" : \"Unrecognized token 'to': was expecting  [line: 1, column: 3]\",\r\n      \"code\" : \"Neo"[…]

Comment: Thanks again William . I just did a little modification on top of your suggestion and it worked. :)  data:JSON.stringify({to: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/584", type: "test"}), where 584 is Neo4j  autogenerated id.

Comment: Great- glad you got it working! FYI you can also pass Cypher statements using the REST api [transactional cypher endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) which can sometimes be easier to work with.